# Download a file to PC using wget command

Tags: ubuntu, download, cloud, wget, remote-server

I want to download a file from a cloud server to my PC using wget command in Ubuntu. Following is what I executed in terminal.

```
wget --output-document=backup.sql http://example.com/backups/20.08.15_08.41.sql
```

It says file 'backup.sql' is saved. But when I check in my downloads I don't see a file like that. Please help me to find where I have been done the wrong thing.

Comment: By the way the `-output-document=backup.sql` parameter is working correctly on my version of wget "GNU Wget 1.15 built on linux-gnu.", could you add your version of wget ?

Comment: Yeah.. It is the same version of mine (GNU Wget 1.15 built on linux-gnu). When I execute the command for the very first time, it worked very well. But now I do not see the file in my downloads.

Comment: what directory are you using `wget` from ? could you specify an **absolute path** for the output file, so you would be sure of the output location ?

Comment: I did not specifically give an absolute path. Since I am downloading the file and gonna save it locally, shouldn't it be saved in downloads?? Because, at the very first time, I could see the file in my downloads.

Comment: it should be saved in the path you ran `wget`, if you ran it in your `home directory` it will  be there, if you ran it from `Downloads` it would be there, that is why you have more control by specifying an absolute path

Comment: I ran wget in root directory. Does that mean, do these files have to be saved in root?

Comment: not if you don't have permission to write there

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
wget -P /home/username/Downloads http://example.com/backups/20.08.15_08.41.sql/backup.sql